# A simple macro which will quick print the active sheet in black and white

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I need to print 100s of similar Excel sheets every quarter. I have set a macro to automate the editing. However, 3 out of every 10 (Apx) pages, when set to quick print, come out in color which makes the text illegible.

I want a macro to set the page in black and white (in page setup settings), then quick print it.
The ChatGPT code (below) results in an error.

```
Sub PrintAllSheetsInBlackAndWhite()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In Worksheets
      ws.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = True
      ws.PrintOut
  Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I really don't have skills to modify macro.  I feel really lost with all these codes. Thanks for the help though. Someone shared a code below. But upon running it an error pops up saying "sub or function not defined".

Answer (score 1):

If there is a hidden sheet, you should include a condition to check if the sheet is visible using ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible before printing, as  below.

```
Sub PrintAllSheetsInBlackAndWhite()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        if ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible then
            ws.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = True
            ws.PrintOut
        end if
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting an error.  "sub or function not defined."

Comment: I couldn't duplicate your error. Which line the error occurred?

Comment: Ok so I tried the same code in my personal PC it worked. I copy paste the exact same thing in my work pc, why would it not work?

Comment: Why in the second line it's worksheet not worksheets?

Comment: When you use the For Each...In loop to iterate through a collection, such as Worksheets, the loop variable (ws in this case) represents an object within that collection.